# How to assign "dispatch_get_main_queue()" to a constant in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-async

Can't get a clue - how to assign "dispatch_get_main_queue()" to a constant in Swift?

For example in Objective-C it looks following:

```
#define kMainQueue dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

Should I use typealias in this case, or smth else?
Thank you

Comment: http://blog.koder.me/ios/2015/11/13/ObjectiveC-Macros-to-swift-constants.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
let kMainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

`kMainQueue` is a constant thanks to the `let`

Comment: Thank you very much. I was playing around "typealias" because of #define in obj-c )
Always forget about "let" or "static let" )